# How to suppress warnings of unused parameter for overridden method in scala?

Tags: scala, compiler-warnings

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964571/scala-2-12-2-emits-a-ton-of-useless-warning-parameter-value-in-method) it is possible to suppress any warnings of unused parameters.

However, I think suppressing all the cases can actually hide bugs, so I want a more granular way for suppressing those.

There is a definite use case, where this warning in most cases is meaningless, I will explain it via an example.

For example the following hypothetical piece of code of a proxy:

```scala
trait HeadersGenerator {
  def generateHeaders(request: Request): Seq[(String, String)]
}

class HeaderMutator extends HeadersGenerator {
  override def generateHeaders(request: Request): Seq[(String, String)] = {
    val oldValue = request.getHeader("SomeHeader")    

    Seq("SomeHeader" -> s"$oldValue - new")
  }
}

class ConstantHeaderGenerator extends HeadersGenerator {
  // here the 'request' parameter is not in use, and needed to be suppressed - 
  // it is not interesting that we do not use it here, since we 
  // don't have anything to do with that because it is inherited
  override def generateHeaders(request: Request): Seq[(String, String)] = {
    Seq("GeneratedHeader" -> "something")
  }

  // here the 'unused' parameter is interesting, and I would like to see a warning
  private def shouldWarn(unused: String) {
    // the parameter is not un use here
  }
}

// somewhere in code
val headers = Seq(
  new HeadersMutator,
  new ConstantHeaderGenerator
).flatMap(_.generateHeaders(request))
```

Comment: You can use [silencer](https://github.com/ghik/silencer)

Comment: I haven't checked but I have a feeling that this has been fixed. If the method is an override then I'm pretty sure it doesn't generate a warning if the parameters are unused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [this annotation](https://www.scala-lang.org/2021/01/12/configuring-and-suppressing-warnings.html#local-warning-suppression-using-nowarn) for compiler:

```scala
  private def shouldWarn(@nowarn unused: String) {
    // the parameter is not in use here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use `_` instead of a parameter name, in your case request, the warning will go away. You don't have to name parameters if you don't use them.

Comment: doesn't work this way, at least in scala 2

Answer (score 0):

One can always use one's parameters in a way that does nothing. For example:

```
object CombinatoryLogic {
    def unused[T](arg: T): Unit = arg match { case _ => () }

    // Church encoding of true
    def k[A, B](consequent: A, alternative: B): A = {
        unused(alternative)
        consequent
    }
}
```

On my scale it's a moderate kludge. On the benefit side, it's always available.