# How to configure `sbt` to not display warnings "Warning private default argument in object * is never used"

Tags: scala, sbt, warnings, compiler-warnings

I have a scala compiler `2.12.11` and compiler prints some warnings, like:
`private default argument in class SomeClass is never used`
while as it is used.

I have seen a [Scala 2.12.2 emits a ton of useless "Warning: parameter value ... in method ... is never used" warnings. How to get rid of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964571/scala-2-12-2-emits-a-ton-of-useless-warning-parameter-value-in-method/43965697) however it doesn't help me, as it is not possible to negate `params`.
Can you help me to surpress this warning, however saving another `unused` warnings? Currently, I have `-Xlint` option.

Comment: Can you please share your `build.sbt` and a piece of code to reproduce it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `-Xlint` which is a batch, you can turn on specific options manually. For instant in 2.13 I can print available options like this:

```
scalac -Xlint:help
Enable recommended warnings
  adapted-args            An argument list was modified to match the receiver.
  nullary-unit            `def f: Unit` looks like an accessor; add parens to look side-effecting.
  inaccessible            Warn about inaccessible types in method signatures.
  infer-any               A type argument was inferred as Any.
  missing-interpolator    A string literal appears to be missing an interpolator id.
  doc-detached            When running scaladoc, warn if a doc comment is discarded.
  private-shadow          A private field (or class parameter) shadows a superclass field.
  type-parameter-shadow   A local type parameter shadows a type already in scope.
  poly-implicit-overload  Parameterized overloaded implicit methods are not visible as view bounds.
  option-implicit         Option.apply used an implicit view.
  delayedinit-select      Selecting member of DelayedInit.
  package-object-classes  Class or object defined in package object.
  stars-align             In a pattern, a sequence wildcard `_*` should match all of a repeated parameter.
  strict-unsealed-patmat  Pattern match on an unsealed class without a catch-all.
  constant                Evaluation of a constant arithmetic expression resulted in an error.
  unused                  Enable -Wunused:imports,privates,locals,implicits,nowarn.
  nonlocal-return         A return statement used an exception for flow control.
  implicit-not-found      Check @implicitNotFound and @implicitAmbiguous messages.
  serial                  @SerialVersionUID on traits and non-serializable classes.
  valpattern              Enable pattern checks in val definitions.
  eta-zero                Usage `f` of parameterless `def f()` resulted in eta-expansion, not empty application `f()`.
  eta-sam                 The Java-defined target interface for eta-expansion was not annotated @FunctionalInterface.
  deprecation             Enable -deprecation and also check @deprecated annotations.
  byname-implicit         Block adapted by implicit with by-name parameter.
  recurse-with-default    Recursive call used default argument.
  unit-special            Warn for specialization of Unit in parameter position.
  multiarg-infix          Infix operator was defined or used with multiarg operand.
  implicit-recursion      Implicit resolves to an enclosing definition.
Default: All choices are enabled by default.
```

so I could e.g. enable `-Xlint:inaccessible -Xlint:adapted-args -Wunused:privates,locales` or whatever I want instead of everything. For 2.12 this list would be different. (You can also check `scalac -X`, `scalac -Y` and `scalac -W`).

An alternative is to enable warnings and suppress them when you "breaking" something consciously. For unused you have `@scala.annotation.unused`, for other warnings in 2.12 and before there is [silencer](https://github.com/ghik/silencer) plugin and since 2.13 there is `@scala.annotation.nowarn` annotation.